# How can I use requests.session.post when I have no name attribute?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to web scrape a site that requires me to log in.
I use python to do the job, but the code I cannot perform the login process. I get the result that I get when I failed in login.

I found out we need to use the name attribute in html code the key of login information dictionary that is the input for the request.session.post().

For example, Zara's login page has name attribute "email" and "password" like as below:

```html
<input id="email" name="email" type="text" value="" autocomplete="off" class="validation-ok" aria-invalid="false">
<input id="password" name="password" type="password" value="" autocomplete="off" class="validation-ok" aria-invalid="false">
```

I could not use it because I cannot see it when I inspected the site in chrome. I believe I could not perform login in Python because I did not use the name attribute as the key for the login information dictionary. The related html code of the website is as follows:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email" required="" autofocus="">
<input type="password" class="form-control" id="pw" placeholder="Password" required="">
```

My question is, how can I write the login information dictionary when I do not have any name attribute in the html code?

I tested my code for Zara website that has a name attribute to scrape the personal account page, and it worked perfectly fine. The only difference was I could use the name attribute for this.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#login information
email = "fakeid@site.com"
password = "fakepassword"
login_info = {"email": email, "pw": password}

#url information
login_url = "https://fakesite.com/admin"
scrape_url = "https://fakesite.com/admin/manageUser"

session = requests.session()

# Perform login
session.post(url=login_url, data=login_info)
response = session.get(url=scrape_url)

#Scrape url
html = response.content
print(html)

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    print('Link href: ' + link['href'])
    print('Link text: ' + link.text)
```

Comment: You should do a `session.get()` on the website (just as you do when you open the login page in your browser) before doing the post.

Answer (score 0):

It's a post with json payload and there's what looks like a csrf token:

[image]

This might be too hard for you to figre out, in which case, switch to selenium.